# SF 1.4 Unexpected extra form fields in an embedform (to update tables)

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

Good morning.
I'm here to solicit the community about **embedded forms with Symfony 1.4**.
I have **two models, with a relation one-to-many**.
I **generate the first model and all its dependencies before to show the form**.
I always get those errors :
`modelb: Unexpected extra form field named "0". Unexpected extra form field named "1". Unexpected extra form field named "2". Unexpected extra form field named "3". Unexpected extra form field named "4". Unexpected extra form field named "5". Unexpected extra form field named "6". Unexpected extra form field named "7". Unexpected extra form field named "8". Unexpected extra form field named "9". Unexpected extra form field named "10". Unexpected extra form field named "11".`
I also tried with `embedRelation()` and I got the same.
Here are summaries of the two **model schemas** :

```
ModelA:
  columns:
    model_d_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    comments: { type: string(1024), notnull: false }
  relations:
    ModeleD: ...

ModelB:
  columns:
    model_a_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    model_b_id: { type: integer, notnull: false }
    model_c_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    is_selected: { type: boolean, notnull: true }
  relations:
    ModelA:
      class: ModelA
      local: model_a_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
      foreignAlias: ModelB
    ModelB: ...
    ModelC: ...
```

So, in the form I want to be able to update the `comments` of `ModelA`, and to have checkboxes for `is_selected` for each entry of `ModelB` related to the current ModelA.
Here is what the form looks like :

```
[] modele_b_entry_name_1
[] modele_b_entry_name_2
[] modele_b_entry_name_3

text
[_______________________________]

[ Submit ]
```

Here is the code of **the embedded form** :

```
class ModelBForm extends BaseModelBForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    unset($this['model_a_id'], $this['model_b_id'], $this['model_c_id'], $this['updated_at']);

    $model_a = $this->getObject();

    $this->setWidget('is_selected', new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(
        array('label' => $model_a->ModelC->getName()),
        array()
      ));
    $this->setValidator('is_selected', new sfValidatorBoolean());
  }
}
```

Here is the **collection of the previous embedded form** :

```
class ModelBCollectionForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $all_model_b = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('ModelB p')
      ->where('p.model_a_id = ?', $this->getOption('model_a_id'))
      ->execute();

    foreach ($all_model_b as $index => $model_b) {
      $form = new ModelBForm($model_b);
      $this->embedForm($index, $form);
    }
  }
}
```

And now **the global form** :

```
class ModelAForm extends BaseModelAForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
      unset($this['created_at'], $this['model_d_id']);

      $subForm = new ModelBCollectionForm(null,
          array('model_a_id' => $this->getObject()->getId())
        );
      $this->embedForm('allmodelb', $subForm);
    }
}
```

The template just shows the form simply.
So the first action shows the form, with with existing entries of the table, and then when you submit the form, here is the code :

```
public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST) || $request->isMethod(sfRequest::PUT));
  $this->form = new ModelAForm();
  var_dump($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
  foreach($this->form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors() as $key => $error)
  {
    echo '<p>' . $key . ': ' . $error . '</p>';
  }
  var_dump($this->form->getValues());
}
```

The first `var_dump()` shows a complete array with good datas. The second one is empty.
I'm working on it for hours but I don't succeed **to bind the form with POST datas**.

Thanks for your help !

Edit : I tried to override bind methods, but it didn't work... Except if I unset ModelB datas, but then the `save()` method will do an INSERT instead of UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
Here is the solution :

```
public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST) || $request->isMethod(sfRequest::PUT));

  $model_a_array = $request->getParameter('model_a');
  $id_model_a = $model_a_array['id'];
  $model_a = Doctrine::getTable('ModelA')->find($id_model_a);
  $this->form = new ModelAForm($model_a);

  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
  if($this->form->isValid()) {
    $this->form->save();
  }
}
```